# repeated digit in ruby using if clause

Tags: ruby

I wrote a piece of code to return `false` when there is a repeated digit in the number passed to the method like this.

```
no_repeat(2114567) #=> false
```

The following is the code. I could not find what is wrong with it. Any suggestion to improve this please.

```
def no_repeat(x)
    x = x.to_s.split('')
    i = 0
    while i < x.length
        if x[i].to_s == x[i + 1]
            false
        end 
        i += 1
    end
    true
end

no_repeat(2114567) #=> true
```

Comment: I just noticed that the method returns false if the repeated digits are consecutive. puts no_repeat(2114567) // false but  puts no_repeat(2145617) //  true. Is it possible to update it to avoid this ?

Comment: Question is not clear. What is the method supposed to return in the other cases?

Comment: It is supposed to return false. But it is returning true

Comment: No. What is it supposed to return when it is not supposed to return false?

Comment: What class is this assignment for?

Comment: Another way would be: `n.to_s.split('').chunk { |i| i }.to_a.map(&:last).max_by(&:size).size == 1` (but I prefer what I've used in my answer).

Answer (score 6):

`false` does not return function unless it is the last expression of the function; explicitly return it.

```
def no_repeat(x)
    x = x.to_s.split('')
    i = 0
    while i < x.length
        if x[i].to_s == x[i + 1]
            return false # <--------
        end 
        i += 1
    end
    true
end

no_repeat(2114567)  # => false
no_repeat(1234)     # => true
```

---

'12345'.each_char.each_cons(2).any? { |x, y| x == y }
false
'11345'.each_char.each_cons(2).any? { |x, y| x == y }
true

Alternative using regular expression (capturing group, backreference):

```
def no_repeat(x)
  ! (/(.)\1/ === x.to_s)
end
```

---

Another alternative suggested by p11y using `each_cons`:

```
'12345'.each_char.each_cons(2).none? { |x, y| x == y }
# => true
'11345'.each_char.each_cons(2).none? { |x, y| x == y }
# => false

'12345'.each_char.each_cons(2).all? { |x, y| x != y }
# => true
'11345'.each_char.each_cons(2).all? { |x, y| x != y }
# => false
```

Comment: Actually the loop is erroneous, too. It iterates beyond the last element because of the `x[i + 1]`. It should be `while i < (x.length - 1)`. Alternatively one could use a more Rubyesque solution like this one: `x.to_s.split('').each_cons(2).any? {|x,y| x == y}`

Comment: @p11y, It's safe to access beyond the array. It will return `nil`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. can you please explain how the regular expression work?

Comment: It may be safe, but it ain't very pretty :)

Comment: @p11y, Thank you for the suggestion of `each_cons`. I updated the answer to include the suggestion.

Comment: The dot means any character. The parentheses are a capture group which is needed so you can refer to it later. The `\1` means "same as the first capture group", so you're basically searching for any character, directly followed by the same character.

Comment: Last suggestion: `collection.none?` seems better than `! collection.any?`

Comment: @falsetru ok, you're right, but it took me three re-reads to finally understand the question. Deleting my answer as it makes no sense in this context.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel, FYI, I was commenting on your answer to mention that you can put counts instead of arrays into the hash: `x.to_s.each_char.reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |m,v| m[v] += 1; m }.all?{|k,v| v == 1}`

Answer (score 1):

```
def no_repeat(n)
  s = n.to_s
  s.size == s.squeeze.size
end

no_repeat(2114567)  #=> false
no_repeat(-2114567) #=> false
no_repeat(2141567)  #=> true
```

I suggest you change the method so it returns `true` when there are repeated digits, and rename it to something like `repeated_digits?`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if a digit in a number shows up more than once

```
x.to_s.chars - x.to_s.chars.uniq == 0
```

If you'd like to know if a digit shows up consecutively in a number you could try this

```
x.to_s.chars.each_cons(2).to_a.count{|array|array.uniq.length == 1} > 0
```

Comment: I believe the question concerns adjacent characters.